# Tish'a Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred thirty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peleg ben Eber lived 239 years

Reu ben Peleg lived 239 years

יח וַיְחִי-פֶלֶג שְׁלֹשִׁים שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד אֶת-רְעוּ.  יט וַיְחִי-פֶלֶג אַחֲרֵי הוֹלִידוֹ אֶת-רְעוּ תֵּשַׁע שָׁנִים וּמָאתַיִם שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד בָּנִים וּבָנוֹת. כ וַיְחִי רְעוּ שְׁתַּיִם וּשְׁלֹשִׁים שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד אֶת-שְׂרוּג.  כא וַיְחִי רְעוּ אַחֲרֵי הוֹלִידוֹ אֶת-שְׂרוּג שֶׁבַע שָׁנִים וּמָאתַיִם שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד בָּנִים וּבָנוֹת.

Answer (score 2):

In the year 239 CE, the Tanach was [first published](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origen) in numerous translated languages.

Answer (score 0):

239 is the North American telephone [area code for a large area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_code_239) of Southwest Florida.
That area covers a large section of Florida beach, which (to the best of my knowledge) has many Jews living in that region.

Comment: I know this is incredibly off topic, but which is the real Florida area code - [229](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_code_239) or [225](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Area_code_FL.svg)? The real question is was this downvoted because the '239' of SW FL is not technically numerical but only a signifier, or because it was somehow judged to have less religious merit than necessary for the venue?

Comment: 239 is the code for one section of Florida beach, and I included it because (to the best of my knowledge) many Jews live in that region.

Comment: So I suspected. Add that infomation to the answer and I bet you'll get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The Roshei Teivos of בלהה רחל זלפה לאה is ברזל

ברזל = 239

Comment: +1 why would this have been downvoted??

Answer (score 0):

[239 years from *Avraham*'s birth to *Ever*'s death.](http://web.archive.org/web/20080915215251/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html)